# More Numpy Vectorization instead of using nested loops

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization

I have `all_data` as a numpy array with the size of `(2,601)`, `NUM_SAMPLES = 601` and `NUM_CLUSTERS = 3`.
Is there any vector form to build `f`  (a `(601,9)` numpy array) than what using nested for-loops as follows?

```
f = np.empty((0,9), float)
for n in range(NUM_SAMPLES):
    f_n = np.array([[]])
    for m in range(NUM_CLUSTERS):
        f_n = np.hstack( (f_n , z_i(alldata[:,n], m).T))
    f = np.concatenate((f, f_n) , axis=0)
```

*NOTE* : when recalling function `z_i(alldata[:,n], m)`, it returns a `(3,1)` numpy array.

`f` is supposed to be *'F'* in the following formula:
[formula of f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMSfS.png)

Comment: Your problem is the function `z_i`.

Comment: why? What is wrong? Could you please tell me more? @QuangHoang

Comment: what Quang want to say is, that you  could create a function that can input all data and return a `3xn` array or given an array and a `m` creates a `3m xn` or something like that

Comment: `z_i` has to be called once for each combination of `n` and `m`.?  And it's a relatively slow python function? That's your bottleneck!

Comment: @hpaulj I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have some function `z_i` in the middle of your loops, you're more or less stuck with loops. You don't need to do a bunch of really inefficient concats like you're doing, but your array size is so small it probably doesn't matter.

```
f = np.vstack((np.hstack((z_i(alldata[:,n], m).T for m in range(NUM_CLUSTERS)))
               for n in range(NUM_SAMPLES)))
```

If you really want this to run faster you have to look into `z_i` and change how that's working.